# Adding values to Header View Programatically doesn't work in onResume() method?

Tags: java, android

I have a header view in my app's navigation header which contains user's image and name. In the profile activity, logged in status is checked first and if one isn't logged in they are redirected to login activity through Intent and adding flags to bring them back to profile after they have logged in. But after coming back, the header image and text aren't shown. I have to go to some other activity and then come back to see the change.

I tried putting it in onResume, to set the text and image but the app crashes.

Here's the onResume code:

```
if(!session.isLoggedIn()){
        session.checkLogin();

    }
    else {
        HashMap<String, String> user = session.getUserDetails();
        name = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_NAME);
        mobile = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_MOBILE);
        image64 = user.get(SessionManager.KEY_IMAGE);


        putname.setText(Html.fromHtml("<b>" + name + "</b>" + "   " + " (" +  mobile + ")"));



        byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(image64, Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
        profilepicture.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);


    }
```

Also, the same thing is being check in onCreate method. I'm kind of confused to what to do. Please help me out in detail. Will be really grateful to you.

Comment: Please post the stack trace from your logcat.

Comment: Where is `putName`'s value being set? Seems like it's null when you call `setText` for the first time. Shouldn't happen if you set it in `onCreate`.

Comment: I'm adding the full code below.